# SVG code: Can I use point decimals and percentages on all browsers?

Tags: svg, cross-browser, compatibility

In SVG code I used point decimals: .001 instead of 0.001

And percentage number like 50%

I have been told that using these numbers used to be a cross browser incompatibility issue in the past, but I haven't been able to replicate the problem in 5 browsers.

Should I revisit all my SVGs and replace the point decimals and percentages?
Is this not an issue anymore, at least across latest versions of most popular browsers?

Comment: point decimal should work fine. Percentage based units – admittedly, you can't  apply them to all svg style properties (e.g transform:translate()) but actually they are supported since the very first svg specifications. So the main reason you might experience browser related rendering issues is quite likely, you're trying to apply a relative value to a property that doesn't accept relative units and it might be internally fixed or set to defaults by more forgiving browsers (firefox vs chromium – both have some smart error corrections, but  quite different patterns).

Comment: trailing . is a problem, not leading . Percentages don't work everywhere, for instance d values need to be numbers as do viewBox values.

Comment: @herrstrietzel
Thank you kind sirs. Based on your comments I have deduced that if a leading point decimal or a % value work in a few of my browsers, then its safe to assume that they will work in all updated popular browsers, and I should not worry about compatibility. I am new here, I think I must click answer the question myself... :D Thanks gentlemen

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Robert Longson, and @herrstrietzel

Based on their comments I have deduced that leading point decimal (like .0694) and % values (where appropriate), have no compatibility issues.
Simply make sure that your data type supports the values you used by testing in few browsers you have on hand, and if all looks as intended then you are doing it right and its safe to assume that these values will work in all updated popular browsers.